# Flutter Drawer setState After Login/SignUp

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, setstate

When a user signs in on a log-in widget, I'd like to call my drawer's `setState()` to show the user's avatar on the drawer. Does anyone know how to add a listener into the drawer so that it changes its state when a user does Firebase log-in on another unrelated widget?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're trying to close it programatically, you can look here (item 4): https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/drawer/

Comment: You can Build your Drawer Widgets Using StreamBuilder which is hooked to Firebase_Auth and on onAuthStateChanged it can rebuilt again when user sign out or Sign in. Hope this Make sense to you.

Comment: @anmol.majhail Thank you for your answer. I'll try your suggestion.